# Mysql query comma separator

Tags: php, mysql

I having two tables

```
table 1: users
| id | username |
|  1 | john |
|  2 | marry |
|  3 | deep |
|  4 | query |
|  5 | value|
```

and

```
table 2:users_2
| table_2_id | user_id |
|      1     |  2,4    |
```

I need required something like this

```
| table_2_id | username |
|      1     |  marry,query    |
```

anyone can help me for this output in mysql

Comment: Normalize your data. Get rid of jaywalker.

Comment: Yes we can help you out, but for that you need to post your tried query & efforts so far given to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking ?

```
select
`users_2`.`table_2_id` , GROUP_CONCAT(`users`.`username`) as `usernames`
from `users_2`
inner join `users` on  FIND_IN_SET(`users`.`id`,`users_2`.`user_id`)
```

Check output here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c498bc/3

Comment: Yes, why bother with SQL at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.table_2_id,b.username
from users b,users_2 a
where a.table_2_id=b.id
and b.id in(a.user_id)
group by a.table_2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not store a multiple value in a single field. For table `users_2`, the data should be:

```
table_2_id  user_id
1           2
1           4
```

After you normalized your table, you can use mysql GROUP_CONCAT() to get the result in the format you mentioned

```
SELECT
    users_2.table_2_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(users.username) AS username
FROM
    users_2
JOIN
    users ON users.id = users_2.user_id
GROUP BY
    users_2.table_2_id
;
```